# Transform: scale div blocks button below it

Tags: angularjs, css, css-transforms

I customized the `g-recaptcha` widget for my need, and it works perfectly. But weirdly the `ng-click` button just below doesn't work anymore. Don't know why.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
<form>
    ...
    <div class="g-recaptcha" vc-recaptcha key="'secret'"></div>
    <button class="btn-primary" ng-click="clicSignUp()" type="submit">
        Sign Up!
    </button>
</form>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.g-recaptcha {
    transform:scale(0.93);
    transform-origin:0 0;
    margin-bottom: -12px;
}
```

I can't click on the button "Sign Up!" anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `transform` increases the element's stacking order. You can give the button a higher order so that it won't be covered by the div.

```
button {
  position: relative;
}
```

Also apply `z-index: 1;` or any larger number as needed.